# In R, how do I apply a VLOOKUP when an ID column is present but not otherwise relevant?

Tags: r, join, vlookup

There are many related questions here about this issue, particulalry using `left_join` from `dplyr` , but I still can't figure it out.

All I want to do is return `LanguageClean` in `Lookup` based on a match to the `Language` column in `df`. If there is no match, simply return `NA`. I want `LanguageClean` added as a new column to `df`.

I can see that my code below is replicating the `ID`, but I don't want it to. The `ID` column is irrelevant for my purposes here, although I need to retain it in the final dataframe.

```
df <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(18L, 89L, 42L, 161L, 88L, 71L, 
                                      175L, 181L, 133L, 56L, 18L, 89L, 42L, 161L, 88L, 71L, 175L, 181L, 
                                      133L, 56L, 18L, 89L, 42L, 161L, 88L, 71L, 175L, 181L, 133L, 56L
), .Dim = c(10L, 3L)), Language = c("en", "", "lv", "en", "en", 
                                    "de", "en", "ms", "", "en"), Geo = c("us", "", "-", "us", 
                                                                           "us", "gb", "ca", "us", "-", "us")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                    -10L))


lookup <- structure(list(Language = c("af", "ar", "ar", "ar", "ar", "ar", 
                                      "ar", "ar", "ar", "eu", "be", "zh", "zh", "hr", "da", "nl", "en", 
                                      "en", "en", "en", "en", "en", "fo", "fi", "fr", "fr", "gd", "de", 
                                      "de", "de", "he", "hu", "id", "it", "ko", "lv", "mk", "mt", "no", 
                                      "pt", "rm", "ro", "ru", "sr", "sk", "sb", "es", "es", "es", "es", 
                                      "es", "es", "es", "es", "es", "sx", "sv", "ts", "tr", "ur", "vi", 
                                      "ji", "sq", "ar", "ar", "ar", "ar", "ar", "ar", "ar", "ar", "bg", 
                                      "ca", "zh", "zh", "cs", "nl", "en", "en", "en", "en", "en", "en", 
                                      "et", "fa", "fr", "fr", "fr", "ga", "de", "de", "el", "hi", "is", 
                                      "it", "ja", "ko", "lt", "ms", "no", "pl", "pt", "ro", "ru", "sz", 
                                      "sr", "sl", "es", "es", "es", "es", "es", "es", "es", "es", "es", 
                                      "es", "sv", "th", "tn", "uk", "ve", "xh", "zu"), LanguageClean = c("Afrikaans", 
                                                                                                         "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", 
                                                                                                         "Arabic", "Basque", "Belarusian", "Chinese", "Chinese", "Croatian", 
                                                                                                         "Danish", "Dutch", "English", "English", "English", "English", 
                                                                                                         "English", "English", "Faeroese", "Finnish", "French", "French", 
                                                                                                         "Gaelic", "German", "German", "German", "Hebrew", "Hungarian", 
                                                                                                         "Indonesian", "Italian", "Korean", "Latvian", "Macedonian", "Maltese", 
                                                                                                         "Norwegian", "Portuguese", "Rhaeto-Romanic", "Romanian", "Russian", 
                                                                                                         "Serbian", "Slovak", "Sorbian", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", 
                                                                                                         "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", 
                                                                                                         "Sutu", "Swedish", "Tsonga", "Turkish", "Urdu", "Vietnamese", 
                                                                                                         "Yiddish", "Albanian", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", 
                                                                                                         "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Arabic", "Bulgarian", "Catalan", 
                                                                                                         "Chinese", "Chinese", "Czech", "Dutch", "English", "English", 
                                                                                                         "English", "English", "English", "English", "Estonian", "Farsi", 
                                                                                                         "French", "French", "French", "Irish", "German", "German", "Greek", 
                                                                                                         "Hindi", "Icelandic", "Italian", "Japanese", "Korean", "Lithuanian", 
                                                                                                         "Malaysian", "Norwegian", "Polish", "Portuguese", "Romanian", 
                                                                                                         "Russian", "Sami", "Serbian", "Slovenian", "Spanish", "Spanish", 
                                                                                                         "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", "Spanish", 
                                                                                                         "Spanish", "Spanish", "Swedish", "Thai", "Tswana", "Ukrainian", 
                                                                                                         "Venda", "Xhosa", "Zulu")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
                                                                                                                                                                         -124L))

df <- left_join(df, lookup, by="Language")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that your lookup table contains multiple entries for some languages. Hence you end up with multiple matches. So solve your issue you could filter out the distinct or unique combinations from your lookup using `dplyr::distinct`:

```r
library(dplyr)

df <- left_join(df, distinct(lookup, Language, LanguageClean),  by = "Language")
df
#>    ID.1 ID.2 ID.3 Language Geo LanguageClean
#> 1    18   18   18       en  us       English
#> 2    89   89   89                       <NA>
#> 3    42   42   42       lv   -       Latvian
#> 4   161  161  161       en  us       English
#> 5    88   88   88       en  us       English
#> 6    71   71   71       de  gb        German
#> 7   175  175  175       en  ca       English
#> 8   181  181  181       ms  us     Malaysian
#> 9   133  133  133            -          <NA>
#> 10   56   56   56       en  us       English
```